# ASP.NET MVC MapRoute: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an application which uses a Web Service. This web service uses the MVC Framework for .NET.

In the web service, I added extra parameters to a method in the controller, and therefore changed the Global.asax.cs file to add those parameters to the specific method's route. However, when I run the application now, I get the error:

> *ArgumentException was unhandled by user code: An item with the same key has already been added.*

I did not create another MapRoute, I just updated the existing MapRoute for that specific method to have extra parameters.

Do I have to do anything else with the routing or another file after I change the number of parameters in a method in the controller?

Why would I be getting a same key issue when there is only one MapRoute to that method name?

Comment: Could you please add the relevant `RouteConfig.cs` code?

Comment: Delete the code in your "bin" directory and re-compile your application.

Comment: "and therefore changed the Global.asax.cs file to add those parameters to the specific method's route" - the `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs` file exists for a reason. You should pretty much never actually touch the code in `Global.asax.cs`, especially not for something like routing.